# WPF DataGrid CellFormating

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF with Auto Generated Columns. Sometimes there are DateTime Fields in it, and i'm looking for a way to format those fields into a proper Format. At the moment i get the Format like this: 
"17/05/2011 12:00:00 AM" 
and it should look like this:
"17/05/2011"
All the Data come from DataTables and i set the DataContext of the DataGrid.
I really don't want to make Templates for all the possible Tables i can show on the DataGrid.

Any suggestions?

Mfg Lim

Issue solved thanks to Bas see

http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/55784/286350.aspx

Comment: Use the AutoGeneratingColumn event, I think it allows you to adjust the binding. (Set a stringformat)

Comment: Thanks very much i was on the complete wrong path :) Found it with that tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the comments from Bas.
Use the AutoGeneratingColumn event, I think it allows you to adjust the binding. (Set a stringformat)